# IIS Rewrite - Condition for ignoring external URLs

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I use the following rule to change the path of every image file to .webp. Except for the subdirectories typo3, fileadmin and upload. That works fine.

But the website also loads external images. These URLs shouldnt be changed to .webp

So I added

another condition

```
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com" ignoreCase="true" />
```

In the rule test interface in IIS it works fine. I use an imagepath from my own domain. The rule test says the pattern fits. If I use an external image path, the pattern did not fit.

BUT if I load a page on my website with different images from different URLs all paths are changed to .webp and this means, that the external ones are not found (404).

How can I make this work?

```
 <rule name="Webp" enabled="true">
                <match url="(.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$" ignoreCase="true" />
               
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT}" pattern="image/webp" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com" />
                    <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/{R:0}.webp" matchType="IsFile" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="typo3/" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="fileadmin/" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="uploads/" negate="true" />      
                                    
                    
                </conditions>
                                                             
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="ACCEPTS_WEBP" value="true" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.webp" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                                   
                                                 
                                   
            </rule>         
            
        </rules>


         <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
 <rule name="jpg to webp" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml" enabled="true">
```

```
                 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false"> 
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="typo3/" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="fileadmin/" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="uploads/" negate="true" />                                      
                    
                    
                                        
                </conditions>
```

Comment: set the condition to <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com" negate="true" />

Comment: Enable FRT to learn more about the incoming requests, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Then you can see what changes are needed for different types of web contents. Merely reviewing the config file is less helpful.

Comment: negate=true does not work and is not needed. The logic is that if the domain is correct, the rewrite should took place.

Comment: In the logs of the failed redirects is nothing to see. I think its because everything "works" in a technical manner. But the condition fails when it comes to the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I have something new. The external images (and more information) are a response to an AJAX call like this from my own domain.

https://www.example.org:443/index.php?tx_jsdshopware_searchview%5B__referrer%2D%5B%40extension%5D=JsdShopware&tx_jsdshopware_searchview%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40controller%5D=SearchView&tx_jsdshopware_searchview%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40action%5D=list&tx_jsdshopware_searchview%5B__referrer%5D%5Barguments%5D=YTowOnt9af44e2e88d7b23601117be0ff9656fd98a839a38&tx_jsdshopware_searchview%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40request%5D=%7B%22%40extension%22%3A%22JsdShopware%22%2C%22%40controller%22%3A%22SearchView%22%2C%22%40action%22%3A%22list%22%7D2eb573bf2f44341434ca68abb64479da78fd5613&tx_jsdshopware_searchview%5B__trustedProperties%5D=%7B%22searchword%22%3A1%2C%22action%22%3A1%7D0a3b9fd37c893b374a4bb4c2daaa7dd2afa90ccc&tx_jsdshopware_searchview%5Bsearchword%5D=footest&type=4321&tx_jsdshopware_searchview%5Baction%5D=ajaxCall&_=13212131

Can I exclude the rewriting of the filenames my filtering for "ajax" ? I have no experience with these technology.